# Firebase password resets

Tags: authentication, passwords, reset, firebase

I'm trying to create a password reset mechanism and am stuck.  Any suggestions how to do this with Firebase basic email/password authentication

Comment: Engineer at Firebase here. We haven't yet rolled out the feature to reset user passwords yet, but hope to soon. I've added you to our Feature Waitlist for this feature, and will follow-up here once we've moved forward. Also, feel free to comment me directly at rob *at* firebase.com if you want to know more. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

[Engineer at Firebase - Update 2014-01-27]

Firebase Simple Login now supports password resets for email / password authentication.

Each of the Simple Login client libraries has been given a new method for generating password reset emails for the specified email address - `sendPasswordResetEmail()` on the Web and Android, and `sendPasswordResetForEmail()` on iOS.

This e-mail will contain a temporary token that the user may use to log into their account and update their credentials. This token will expire after 24 hours or when the user changes their password, whichever occurs first.

Also note that Firebase Simple Login enables full configuration of the email template as well as the sending address (including whitelabel email from your domain for paid accounts).

To get access to this feature, you'll need to update your client library to a version of `v1.2.0` or greater. To grab the latest version, check out https://firebase.google.com/docs/.

Also, check out https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth for the latest Firebase Simple Login - Web Client docs.

Comment: Is it possible to customise this reset email?

Comment: @Rob DiMarco Thanks! but why firebase allows using old password even after i manually reset the password for that account from the consoles. Is it the expected behavior?

Comment: @Preetam Yes - that action in the console sends the user a password reset email, but it doesn't change the password on the account.

Answer (score 4):

This is something that Firebase doesn't do very well.  As you'll notice it requires the user to remember their old password.  Usually if you want to reset a password it's because you've forgotten it.  Hopefully the improve the methods they provide for account management.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/simple-login-email-password.html

```
authClient.changePassword(email, oldPassword, newPassword, function(error, success) {
  if (!error) {
    console.log('Password change successfully');
  }
});
```

Comment: This is after you're logged in, notice it requires the oldpassword.  I'm asking for password resets that don't require knowledge of the old password because the user forgot them,.

Comment: Then I don't know. You could delete the user and re-create, but then you'd have to swap around all the references to it.

Answer (score 0):

This was the first google result that came up when trying to figure out my issue.. for anyone who uses yeoman angularfire generator but would like to add the send email feature, this should work.
add the following to the simple login factory in simpleLogin.js:

```
   resetPassword: function(emailIn){
       return auth.$resetPassword({
          email: emailIn
        }, function(error) {
          if (error) {
            switch (error.code) {
              case "INVALID_USER":
                console.log("The specified user account does not exist.");
                break;
              default:
                console.log("Error resetting password:", error);
            }
          } else {
            console.log("Password reset email sent successfully!");
          }
      });
    },
```

and call it from your login.js file

```
  $scope.resetPassword = function(email){

  simpleLogin.resetPassword(email)
};
```